# How to target database connection file once in PHP?

Tags: php, filepath

My PHP application has different config files with their different settings and their different paths. But all of them need to access to just one database connection file. I would like to avoid mention its path separately on them with many `../` and `../../`. How can I write a same code and use it in all of them?
Imagine that my PHP application has this hierarchy for its config files:

> root
>     root/config/db.php  (This file is what I want to mention from all config files.)
>     root/admin/config/conf.php
>     root/users/conf.php

Actually what I need is something that detect the root path of my project and create a same directory path generally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and then path to your file.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's class autoloading, the catch being you then need to wrap up your config information in a class, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once("../../config/db.php");
```

Include this file into "conf.php" file

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`include_path`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) directive as either `root/` or `root/config/` either by editing your php.ini file or by calling [`set_include_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) on every page. This way, you can just `include/require "db.php"` on each page.